# How do I get my audio to play in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a couple updates to my socket.io chat and I am trying to get audio every time a message is passed through. When I send the message I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`
Here is the code that gets run when a message is passed through:

```
socket.on('new message', (data) => {
            var messageE = document.createElement('div')
            messageE.classList.add("well");
            messageE.classList.add("msg");
            messageE.innerHTML = '<strong>'+ data.user +'</strong>: ' + data.msg;
            console.log(messageE)

            chat.appendChild(messageE)
            audio.play()
          })
```

I may wont be able to respond till late afternoon.

Comment: please share more details about the used platform and plugins

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775957/playing-audio-file-returns-uncaught-in-promise-but-works-in-console) for browser play policy. Might be the problem in your case.

Comment: Since it is saying `DOMException`, try wrapping your function in Try Catch block. To get exact error. Can you check the data object?

Assuming you have `audio` node defined in a way so that it can be accessed inside the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

A few seconds ago i got the same error but i fixed it. It is not the coolest solution but it works.
What i did telling the browser itself to play the audio and not directly from a socket.

Make a outside Variable(example socketCheck) that is on **false**. That will become **true** when the socket is called. The *if* will continue when it is on **true** on **false** it wont. When the sound got played turn the soundCheck on **false** again
Here is a example;

```
var soundCheck = false;

socket.on('new message', function(){
    soundCheck = true;
});

if (soundCheck) {
    sound.play();
    sound = false;
}
```