# Audio object not playing jasmine angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to playing audio object in my `spec.ts` file with below code

```
it("it should play audio",()=>{
  new Audio("url of the file").play().then(res=>{
      console.log("audio played successfully");
   })
})
```

but it throws below error.

> NotAllowedError: play() failed because user did not interact with the document

Angular version: 9.0

**This question is different because now in unit test we are not able to play any audio and because of the we are unable to get play and playing event from the audio object.
[Please read chrome blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing audio file returns "Uncaught (in promise)" but works in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775957/playing-audio-file-returns-uncaught-in-promise-but-works-in-console)

Comment: @IAfanasov No, In that they mention in chrome browser it will throw error, and I tried
``` document.getElementById('audio').autoplay = true; document.getElementById('audio').muted = true; document.getElementById('audio').play(); ```
which mention in the comments but that is also not working
after trying this it is still throwing 
"NotAllowedError: play() failed because user did not interact with the document"